# how to add suffix y-axes on filament bar chart

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js, filamentphp

I use *filamentphp 2.x* for generating dashboard with some widgets in it.
One of the widget that I need is a bar chart widget.
And than a problem occurs when I want to add suffix onto Y-axis label.
In chartJs is so easy cause it is using javascript:

```
options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return value + ' Mb';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

While in *filamentphp*, options is written as a separate php variable and as an array.

```
protected static ?array $options = [];
```

I'm not sure how I can write this callback within my widget class.
I tried the following

```
public string $suffixValue = 'Mb';
protected static ?array $options = [
        'scales' => [
            'y' => [
                'ticks' => [
                    "callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return value + ' {$this->suffixValue}'
                    }",
                ],
            ],
        ],
];
```

but it resulted the bar chart was not displayed.

Or if I tried like this

```
protected static ?array $options = [
        'scales' => [
            'y' => [
                'ticks' => [
                    'callback' => "function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return value + ' {$this->suffixValue}'
                    }",
                ],
            ],
        ],
];
```

The bar chart is displayed, however the Y-axis label is missing.

How can I achieve this adding suffix in the bar chart using filamentphp?

Comment: see the main culprit making callback function not rendered properly is @json within chart-widget.blade.php